# My Program Will Not Draw An Ellipse in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, ellipse

I'm pretty new to python and pygame and I can't seem to draw a ellipse.
Please help!

I'm running this in python3.10.

Here is all of the source code below.

My only suspicion is this code is in python2 cause I used to code in python2 and then I stopped so python3 is new to me.

Whoever fixes it thank you so much!!

```
    from pygame import *
    import pygame
    
    init()

    S0 = 640
    S1 = 480

    screen = display.set_mode((S0, S1))
    display.set_caption("Zero-Player-Game")

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    x = 10
    y = 10

   dx = 1
   dy = 2

   Black = (0, 0, 0)
   White = (255, 255, 255)

   p_size = 50

   end = False

   while not end:
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                end = True
            x += dx
            y += dy
            if y < 0 or y > S1 - p_size:
                dy *= -1
            if x < 0 or x > S0 - p_size:
                dx *= -1
            screen.fill(Black)
            draw.ellipse(screen, White, (x, y, p_size, p_size))
            clock.tick(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse isn't being drawn because you forgot to update the display inside the `while` loop. Just type `pygame.display.update()` or `display.update()` at the bottom of your `while` loop in order to do that.

## Code

```
from pygame import *
import pygame

init()

S0 = 640
S1 = 480

screen = display.set_mode((S0, S1))
display.set_caption("Zero-Player-Game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 10
y = 10

dx = 1
dy = 2

Black = (0, 0, 0)
White = (255, 255, 255)

p_size = 50

end = False

while not end:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            end = True
        x += dx
        y += dy
        if y < 0 or y > S1 - p_size:
            dy *= -1
        if x < 0 or x > S0 - p_size:
            dx *= -1
        screen.fill(Black)
        draw.ellipse(screen, White, (x, y, p_size, p_size))
        clock.tick(100)
        pygame.display.update()
```

## Edit

The person who asked the question also had an issue with lag. The game is lagging because the code that is responsible for drawing and moving the ellipse is inside the event loop (`for event in event.get()`). So to fix the lag, simply move that code to after the loop.

## Modified Code

```
from pygame import *
import pygame

init()

S0 = 640
S1 = 480

screen = display.set_mode((S0, S1))
display.set_caption("Zero-Player-Game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 10
y = 10

dx = 1
dy = 2

Black = (0, 0, 0)
White = (255, 255, 255)

p_size = 50

end = False

while not end:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            end = True
    x += dx
    y += dy
    if y < 0 or y > S1 - p_size:
        dy *= -1
    if x < 0 or x > S0 - p_size:
        dx *= -1
    screen.fill(Black)
    draw.ellipse(screen, White, (x, y, p_size, p_size))
    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great. Btw do you know why the program lags so much?

Comment: @ChanceMeteor515, I looked at your code again and noticed that the ellipse's movement is done inside the event loop, which is the `for event in event.get()`. If you move the code that is used to draw and move the sprite to outside of that loop, it won't lag. I will edit my answer.